# VBA Excel-How to show alert when sum of rows of a column crosses a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have two columns as shown above. How can I show an alert box when a user enters a row and the sum of column **salary** is greater than 1000000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the "Salary" is on column B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("B:B"))
If Total >= 1000000 Then
MsgBox "My message", vbCritical, "Error"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Nadeer, i have one more requirement that is i have to calculate the sum of a column when user press a button which is in an another sheet. In that case i think it won't work. Will u plz tell me how to do that one.

Comment: I got it. `Total = Application.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A"))`

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't tied to VBA, you can accomplish this by using `Data Validation`. In Excel 2007, select your range of salaries (let's say column `B`), click on `Data` in the Ribbon and select `Data Validation`. From there, enter the following formula:

```
=B:B<1000000
```

This will throw an error anytime you enter a value that makes the total of the column > 1000000. You can also customize the error if necessary:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it for a single cell, this code needs to be in the vba page for that specific sheet, not in a module. I'm sure you can adapt it to work for your range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then 
        If Range("A1").Value > 1000000
            MsgBox "A1 is greater than 1000000, ALERT! ALERT! ALERT!"
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

But non VBA solutions such as conditional formatting or else data validation like @RocketDonkey has suggested are a better idea.

Comment: +1 to you for doing it in VBA as the question asked though :)